# Parse a Json from a url with entry values and list them in SwiftUI

Tags: json, parsing, swiftui

I'm stuck on this.
I have a json that I'm parsing and that Json has an entry value and I want to do a swift list based in user input that will trigger from the external json different responses.

I have the following code so far

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Foundation

var lokas : String = "ABCY"

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var name: String = ""
    @ObservedObject var fetcher = Fetcher()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter Loka id", text: $name)
            
            List(fetcher.allLokas) { vb in
                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(movie.device)
                    Text(String(vb.seqNumber))
                        .font(.system(size: 11))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

 

public class Fetcher: ObservableObject {

    @Published var allLokas = [AllLoka_Data]()
    
    init(){
        load(devices:lokas)
    }
    
    func load(devices:String) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://xxx.php?device=\(devices)&hours=6")!
    
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data,response,error) in
            do {
                if let d = data {
                    let decodedLists = try JSONDecoder().decode([AllLoka_Data].self, from: d)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.allLokas = decodedLists
                    }
                }else {
                    print("No Data")
                }
            } catch {
                print ("Error")
            }
            
        }.resume()
         
    }
}

struct AllLoka_Data: Codable {
    var date: String
    var time: String
    var unix_time: Int
    var seqNumber : Int
}

// Now conform to Identifiable
extension AllLoka_Data: Identifiable {
    var id: Int { return unix_time }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

But I just added a Global variable to test it, but how do I pass the variable name to make the function work ?
Thank you

Comment: What not working? You want to filter your array?

Comment: I would like to enter the text field and that text filed be passed to the url

Comment: The url has a variable called "devices" that will filter the data, so I'm trying to get the list based on user input of that variable